Docker Image stop exec
I have build my java app as docker image using Dockerfile. I have pushed it to docker hub and is available to my users.
But i do not want any of my users to do docker exec[docker exec -it [container] /bin/bash] and enter into my image and download the jar inside image using log volume.
Want to check if there is any way i can stop anyone from doing exec -it to my image.
Thanks,
Atul

Don't include a shell in the image

They can use docker cp, which is much easier. There is no way to prevent access to the contents of the image.

Docker images can be exported as archives and these archives can be extracted. If you publish your files (whether standalone or as part of a docker image), they are public and others can download them.
